# How to format output or display?

Tags: c++, format, output

```
void listUser(student user[], int size, int const track)
{
    int list;
    cout<< "\n\tName|||Age|||Gender|||Course|||Year|||Section|||Student No.\n";
    for (list=0; list<track; list++)
    {
        cout<< "\n\n" << user[list].firstname <<" " << user[list].lastname <<"\t\t" << user[list].age <<"\t" << user[list].gender << "\t" << user[list].course << "\t" << user[list].year << "\t" << user[list].section << "    " << user[list].studno <<"\n";
    }
    return;
}
```

So, this is a part of my code that displays a list of users on the command-line window. My question is, how do I format the output/display without using tabulators?

It looks ugly and somewhat unpresentable when a user in a list has either a long name or short name. Thanks.

Comment: Check for the [`std::setw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) io manipulator. `std::setfill()`might be useful also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way: iterate the collection **twice**. First to find out the size of the longest string in each column, second to actually print the values.

Pseudo-code:

```
size_longest_first_name = 0
size_longest_last_name = 0

for each student
{
    if (student.first_name.size > size_longest_first_name)
        size_longest_first_name = student.first_name.size

    if (student.last_name.size > size_longest_last_name)
        size_longest_last_name = student.last_name.size
}

for each student
{
    padding_spaces = size_longest_first_name - student.first_name.size() - 
    print student.first_name + string(padding_spaces)

    padding_spaces = size_longest_last_name - student.last_name.size() - 
    print student.last_name + string(padding_spaces)
}
```

**Edit:**

Oh, and don't use an array! That's low-level C-style coding completely inappropriate in a C++ program. Use `std::vector`.